# Can blocks of XAML be repeated, foreach-style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a WPF application that consists of a base-Map with a series of Campsites overlaid on top.

The number of campsites is updated dynamically in a collection, so I want to write XAML that will create more campsite Images as needed.

But I'm not familiar with any sort of `foreach` construct, or other repeating code in XAML.
Does such a thing exist?

```
<Image Name="MapImage" Stretch="None">
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <ImageDrawing ImageSource="{Binding ForestArea}" Rect="{Binding Rect}"/>

<!-- Repeat the campsite as needed -->
                        <ImageDrawing ImageSource="{StaticResource CampSite}" Rect="{Binding Campsite[0].Rect}" />
                        <ImageDrawing ImageSource="{StaticResource CampSite}" Rect="{Binding Campsite[1].Rect}" />
                        <ImageDrawing ImageSource="{StaticResource CampSite}" Rect="{Binding Campsite[2].Rect}" />
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: @GrantWinney: Hey, just knowing that its possible, and what to read up on is a pretty good start.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you just wanting an easy way to have the images/paths of your campsite icon be re-used? Are you using actual images or are you adding other functionality for them where vectors might make a good choice? A ContentControl may just be the way for you to go but based on what you've shown there may be better ways yet. If you want a free hand from a KC, KS neighbor we can get you sorted.

Comment: Is that DrawingImage/ImageDrawing construct strictly necessary? Otherwise, you would usually have an ItemsControl with an Image control in its ItemTemplate. Then you would bind the ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of campsite items.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired behavior pretty easy, if you use an `ItemsControl` with an according `ItemTemplate` to display the images in a `Canvas` instead of the `DrawingGroup`. `Canvas` is a panel control which allows positioning items by coordinates:

```
<!-- Campsites needs to contain an observable collection of all your campsites -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Campsites}">
    <!-- Set a canvas as the panel in whcih the items are rendered -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <!-- Set the forest area as background image of the canvas -->
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ForestArea}" />
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Display campsite image with the respective x, y, width, height -->
            <Image Source="{StaticResource CampSite}" 
                    Canvas.Left="{Binding Rect.X}"
                    Canvas.Top="{Binding Rect.Y}"
                    Width="{Binding Rect.Width}"
                    Height="{Binding Rect.Height}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```